# Spring - @ModelAttribute behaviour

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, modelattribute

I'm having a problem with @ModelAttribute usage.

Having a simple Spring (3.2.11) mvc application with such context:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="spring.test" />
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>
```

Having 2 DTOs: PageDTO and SessionDTO, inside these two DTOs are completely the same, containing just one property - Address address and get/set methods.

```
package spring.test.model;

public class PageDTO implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Address address;
    // getters / setters omitted
}


package spring.test.model;

public class SessionDTO implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Address address;
    // getters / setters omitted
}

package spring.test.model;

public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String street;
    private String houseNo;
    private String city;
    private String zip;    
    // getters/setters omitted
}
```

Having an addressForm.jsp with one form:

```
<c:url var="actionURL" value="/processForm"/>
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="pageDto" action="${actionURL}">
    <form:label path="address.street">Street: </form:label>
    <form:input path="address.street"/>
    <form:label path="address.houseNo">House No: </form:label>
    <form:input path="address.houseNo"/>
    <form:label path="address.city">City: </form:label>
    <form:input path="address.city"/>
    <form:label path="address.zip">ZIP: </form:label>
    <form:input path="address.zip"/>
    <input type="submit" name="searchAddress" value="Submit" />
</form:form>
```

Having a controller:

```
package spring.test.controller;

// imports omitted

@SessionAttributes("sessionDto")
@Controller
public class FormController {

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
    }

    @ModelAttribute("pageDto")
    public PageDTO initPageDTO() {
        return new PageDTO();
    }  

    @ModelAttribute("sessionDto")
    public SessionDTO initSessionDTO() {
        return new SessionDTO();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView renderHome(@ModelAttribute("pageDto") PageDTO pageDto, 
            @ModelAttribute("sessionDto") SessionDTO sessionDto) {       
        return new ModelAndView("addressForm", "pageDto", pageDto);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/processForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView processForm(@ModelAttribute("pageDto") PageDTO pageDto, 
            @ModelAttribute("sessionDto") SessionDTO sessionDto) {
        if(pageDto != null && pageDto.getAddress() != null
                && sessionDto != null && sessionDto.getAddress() != null) {
            System.out.println("pageDto.getAddress().getHouseNo(): " + pageDto.getAddress().getHouseNo());
            System.out.println("sessionDto.getAddress().getHouseNo(): " + sessionDto.getAddress().getHouseNo());
        }
        return new ModelAndView("addressForm", "pageDto", pageDto);
    }

}
```

And here comes the problem. When I submit the address form, both of the DTOs are filled in with the data from the form. I would expect only the model attribute with the "pageDto" name mentioned in the form tag in the jsp to be filled in.

Log entry from the form-submit event:

```
[10/24/14 11:23:09:382 CEST] 0000002b SystemOut     O pageDto.getAddress().getHouseNo(): 41
[10/24/14 11:23:09:382 CEST] 0000002b SystemOut     O sessionDto.getAddress().getHouseNo(): 41
```

When I change the processForm method in the controller like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processForm(@ModelAttribute("pageDto") PageDTO pageDto,
        HttpSession httpSession) {
    SessionDTO sessionDto = (SessionDTO) httpSession.getAttribute("sessionDto");
    if(pageDto != null && pageDto.getAddress() != null
            && sessionDto != null && sessionDto.getAddress() != null) {
        System.out.println("pageDto.getAddress().getHouseNo(): " + pageDto.getAddress().getHouseNo());
        System.out.println("sessionDto.getAddress().getHouseNo(): " + sessionDto.getAddress().getHouseNo());
    }
    return new ModelAndView("addressForm", "pageDto", pageDto);
}
```

...it works as desired - sessionDto is NOT filled in with data from the form, so no entry appears in the log (sessionDto.getAddress() == null).

Motivation to have 2 DTOs, one stored in the session:

- not all properties of the model are displayed on the form, so I would have to use input type=hidden not to loose data
- I need to be able to find out what properties are changed by user when submitting the form

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: Store it in the session yourself and retrieve it. Don't use it as a `@ModelAttribute` because it really isn't that. The problem is that databinding just binds requestparameters to objects based on their name. So if there is a parameter `houseNo` and there is a `setHouseNo` on any model object it will be bound.

Comment: So what is the meaning of the name in @ModelAttribute("name") if not to distinguish the model objects?

Comment: To retrieve the correct object from the model but all model objects are considered for binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At submit time, the name of the `ModelAttribute` has mainly cosmetic effect. The request parameters consist in a *hash* where keys are the paths of  the `<form:input>` elements sent by previous response (*), and the values comes from what user typed in the form. But the name of the `modelAttribute` is **not** in the request and Spring has no way to guess it.

It takes all the `@ModelAttribute` parameters of the method and tries to set the attributes corresponding the to *keys* of the request parameters, and when it's done, puts them in the `Model` **with the name you supplied**.

So the name is only used to prepare the response and not to parse the request.

(*) if the request comes from submitting the form, but it could be produced by any other way - simply Spring MVC expects request parameters following that convention